# Need help writing to a CSV file Python 3.5

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

My code writes to a CSV file titled 'output' [here is a link to past help on this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837007/how-do-i-webscrape-by-manipulating-the-url-python-3-5/48837889#48837889)
When I run my code my CSV file is being rewritten over in the body row. I want to write to a new row every time there is new information being scraped from the table of the [stock table URL](https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=ftft). 
Here is what my CSV file looks like:

```
Index,P/E,EPS (ttm),Insider Own,Shs Outstand,Perf Week,Market Cap,Forward P/E,EPS next Y,Insider Trans,Shs Float,Perf Month,Income,PEG,EPS next Q,Inst Own,Short Float,Perf Quarter,Sales,P/S,EPS this Y,Inst Trans,Short Ratio,Perf Half Y,Book/sh,P/B,EPS next Y,ROA,Target Price,Perf Year,Cash/sh,P/C,EPS next 5Y,ROE,52W Range,Perf YTD,Dividend,P/FCF,EPS past 5Y,ROI,52W High,Beta,Dividend %,Quick Ratio,Sales past 5Y,Gross Margin,52W Low,ATR,Employees,Current Ratio,Sales Q/Q,Oper. Margin,RSI (14),Volatility,Optionable,Debt/Eq,EPS Q/Q,Profit Margin,Rel Volume,Prev Close,Shortable,LT Debt/Eq,Earnings,Payout,Avg Volume,Price,Recom,SMA20,SMA50,SMA200,Volume,Change

-,-,-3.00,45.18%,5.19M,30.47%,15.78M,-,-,0.00%,2.84M,-16.48%,-14.00M,-,-,1.00%,9.24%,88.82%,18.30M,0.86,-122.00%,136.99%,0.26,88.82%,27.27,0.11,-,-,4.00,-51.44%,0.87,3.51,15.00%,-,1.30 - 8.00,-27.10%,-,-,-15.40%,0.40%,-62.00%,2.73,-,1.10,-16.40%,25.10%,133.85%,0.52,450,1.20,-58.50%,-,53.21,19.81% 17.08%,No,0.37,-,-,5.40,2.96,Yes,0.13,-,-,991.40K,3.04,3.00,1.72%,-6.24%,29.44%,"5,358,503",2.70%
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

twiturl = "https://twitter.com/ACInvestorBlog"
twitpage = urllib.request.urlopen(twiturl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(twitpage,"html.parser")

print(soup.title.text)

tweets = [i.text for i in soup.select('a.twitter-cashtag.pretty-link.js-nav b')]
print(tweets)

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
url_list = [url_base + tckr for tckr in tweets]

for url in url_list:

    fpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    fsoup = BeautifulSoup(fpage, 'html.parser')

    #scrape single page and add data to list
    #write datalist
with open('output.csv', 'wt') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    # write header row
    writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2-cp'})))

    # write body row
    writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2'})))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Append mode

The issue is with your command `open('output.csv', 'wt')` - 'w' option opens the file for (over)writing. If you want to append data at the end of the existing file, use the 'a' option instead, as shown in the fine manual at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open .

Also, you might want to check if the file exists beforehand and write the header row only if it does not.

Comment: When using the append option 'a' , my CSV file still only has the final object in the array inputted as the row. How can I put each object of my array as separate rows?